# Efficiently Querying a Large Database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a blacklist stored in a table that contains approximately 1.5 billion records. My goal is to load the records into a HashSet so my program can later check if domain names are blacklisted (this is not the entire functionality of the program, just a piece). I currently have the following code to load the records:

```
    HashSet<String> list = new HashSet<String>();
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.setFetchSize(100000000);
        try {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DNname FROM " + table);
            try {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    list.add(rs.getString(1));
                }
            } finally {
                rs.close();
            }
        } finally {
            stmt.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error loading blacklist from DB");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, this takes incredibly long to complete. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I really question whether you really want to store 1.5 billions records in memory - to do a load and search sounds a lot slower than simply doing a DB search.  But any, setting the HashSet to have a bigger initial Capacity would help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(int)

Comment: Also by setting the fetch size to 100 millions may cause the sql driver to cache this amount of rows - sounds like it would use a lot of memory

Comment: @ScaryWombat I thought the same when I was given this task but wanted to see if it'd be possible. Might have to discuss an alternative with the others. The program will run on a fairly hefty system so memory may not be much of an issue if it provides a big enough speed boost.

Answer (score 0):

1. "this takes incredibly long to complete" - what takes long to complete? How long does the query take if you run it from a DB client console?
2. You've not provided any information on what indexes are present in the table, so that's something you'll want to look into.
3. `setFetchSize` is a **hint** to the JDBC driver - you really want a `WHERE` clause where you can limit the records fetched. Oracle DB can do that using `ROWNUM`; for other DBs, you'll have to look for yourself.

That said, I concur with @ScaryWombat; keeping 1.5 billion records in memory is not scalable design. An alternative would to be build up a client cache by caching the database look up for each domain; in all practicality, the cache will have fewer than 1.5 billion entries.

Comment: Thanks for answering @AbhijitSarkar

1. Longer than is acceptable for the program's purpose
2. I only need to select one column of strings
3. I'm not sure I understand how this would help. Are you saying I should run a series of queries with LIMIT clauses to explicitly fetch data in batches?

Comment: @kjwill555 1. What I'm saying is you need to find out what is slow, the query itself, or the Java code. 2. If you don't know how having an index may speed up query execution, you need to talk to an in-house DBA or DB Dev first. 3. I'm saying add a `ROWNUM < whatever` in your query instead of depending on the DB driver to do that for you.